# How Can I Trigger a Segue From Pan Gesture?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, uipangesturerecognizer

I have the following pan gesture code set up on a UIViewController in a StoryBoard.

In ViewDidLoad:

```
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

Then I have the following called:

```
#pragma mark - GESTURE RECOGNIZERS

- (void)panDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer
{
CGPoint velocity = [panRecognizer velocityInView:self.view];

NSLog(@"Pan Detected.");

if(velocity.x > 0)
{
    NSLog(@"Pan went right.");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Pan went left.");

    if (panRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
        NSLog(@"State Changed.");
}
}
```

The above code fires when I drag my finger from left to right.  I want it to only trigger if I drag from the right edge of the screen.  I then want to segue to a UIViewController that is on another StoryBoard.  (I want to drag on a settings screen modally onto my main screen in the app from the right edge).  The settings UIViewController needs to drag onto the screen only partially.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Settings"])
{
    NSLog(@"Show Settings View Controller");
    OLStoryboardLink *storyboardLink = segue.destinationViewController;
    //send the string
    storyboardLink.setStoryboardName = @"Settings";
    storyboardLink.transitioningDelegate  = self;
    [self presentViewController:storyboardLink animated:YES completion:nil];
}
}
```

How can I trigger the segue from the pan gesture from the right edge of the screen?

Answer (score 2):

Segues can't be performed from a viewController in a storyboard A to a viewController in a storyboard B. To use segues, the 2 viewController have to be in the same Storyboard.

But to answer the question, you trigger a segue by calling the `performSegueWithIdentifier`: method:

```
- (void)panDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer
{
    CGPoint velocity = [panRecognizer velocityInView:self.view];

    NSLog(@"Pan Detected.");

    if (velocity.x > 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Pan went right.");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Pan went left.");     

        if (panRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
            NSLog(@"State Changed.");

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Settings" sender:panRecognizer];
    }
}
```

For more informations, see [Apple's reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:)

Comment: I am currently doing this with RSStoryboardLink but I don't know how to trigger it from a gesture. I can make it work with a UIButton tap.

Comment: Do you have a more full code example?  How can I performSegueWithIdentifier : from my panDetected code?

Comment: do you know how to do the other parts in my question -> drag the panel/uiview into view from the right edge?  Similar to how the control center panel can be dragged up from the bottom or notification area dragged down.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Swift 5 answer if anyone is still looking out -

```
@objc func panDetected(panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let velocity = panGesture.velocity(in: self.view)

    print("Pan Detected.");

    if (velocity.x > 0)
    {
        print("Pan went right.");
    }
    else
    {
        print("Pan went left.");

        if panGesture.state == .changed {
            print("State Changed.");
        }
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "NowPlayingSegue", sender: self)
    }
}
```